# 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ViewController tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance error

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I keep getting this error when I press the search bar. The collectionView is embedded in a viewcontroller and the search bar is outside the collectionView:

[CollectionView inside ViewController](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sg2L6.png)

The datasource and delegate for the collectionView are connected to the viewController they are embedded in. The strange this is I don't even have a tableView present but instead a collectionView.

```
class ChannelViewController: UIViewController, UISearchResultsUpdating, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

  var channelArray: [ChannelInfo] = []
  var filteredSearchResults = [ChannelInfo]()
  var resultsSearchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
  var logosShown = [Bool](count: 50, repeatedValue: false)
  var detailUrl: String?
  var apiKey = ""
  var channel: String!
  var channelForShow: String!

  @IBOutlet var channelCollectionView: UICollectionView!
  @IBOutlet var channelSearchBar: UISearchBar!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    SearchBarAttributes()
    }


  //MARK: CollectionView

 func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    if resultsSearchController.active && resultsSearchController.searchBar.text != ""
    {
      return filteredSearchResults.count
    } else {
      return channelArray.count
    }
  }


 func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
      let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("ChannelCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ChannelCell
    let channel: String
    if resultsSearchController.active && resultsSearchController.searchBar.text != "" {
      channel = self.filteredSearchResults[indexPath.item].logo
    } else {
      channel = self.channelArray[indexPath.item].logo
    }

    return cell
  }

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    var replacedTitle: String?
    if resultsSearchController.active && resultsSearchController.searchBar.text != "" {

      channelForShow = filteredSearchResults[indexPath.item].channelName

    } else {
      channelForShow = self.channelArray[indexPath.item].channelName
    }
    self.dismissSearchBar()
    performSegueWithIdentifier("channelCollectToShowSegue", sender: self)
  }

 //MARK: Search

  func SearchBarAttributes () {

    self.resultsSearchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)//required!
    self.resultsSearchController.searchResultsUpdater = self// required!
    self.resultsSearchController.definesPresentationContext = true//removes search controller if move to other vc
      channelSearchBar = self.resultsSearchController.searchBar
    self.channelCollectionView.reloadData()
  }

  func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {

    self.filteredSearchResults.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
    let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "channelName CONTAINS [c] %@", searchController.searchBar.text!)
    let array = (self.channelArray as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(searchPredicate)
    self.filteredSearchResults = array as! [ChannelInfo]
    self.channelCollectionView.reloadData()
  }
}
```

Here is the storyboard with the Searchbar IB connections:

[image: Storyboard with IB Connections]

Comment: enable excetion breakpoint and see what gets hit when u tap on the searchbar.

Comment: I tried that, but as soon as I hit the search bar the SIGABRT error pops ups before it can reach any breakpoint.

Comment: see if there are any wrong outlet connections in the IB. can you post the screenshot of the IB showing the outlet connections ?

Comment: Can you share your project to help you better? Your code have a lot of missing things, for example in your `cellForItemAtIndexPath` method you never assign the `channel` constant to anything, why?

Comment: @SwiftyJD Seeing your picture I think your problem is not in this ViewController, you are passing data to another ViewController with a `UITableView` isn't?

Comment: I just posted the pic of the IB connections.

Comment: I am passing data to a viewController with an embedded tableView but I haven't connected them in the storyboard yet.

Comment: I agree with Victor, the error is related to another class.

Comment: I would gladly share the project, not sure how to do that on stackoverflow.

Comment: Upload the project to github and then share a link to the github repo here.

Comment: Ok I just uploaded to Github. It's under the new branch: ViewControllerWithCollectionView .  Here is the link:

Comment: https://github.com/asentwo/GuideBoxGuide